# In the event of a horrific death, what is the Halachic minimum of biological materials which must be collected for burial?

Tags: death, funeral-burial-levaya, parts-of-the-body

Hashem requires that a Jew be buried and that the body should be intact. In horrific circumstances, that isn't always possible and there are medical crews who need to collect the remains **(such as a horrific car accident or the awful scenes of the October 7th terror attacks)**

When such events occur there is a process to collect everything so one can to be properly buried. This is usually done by EMTs and similar medical crews. My question is to what extent is that process followed and does Halacha define the minimum of biological materials necessary for burial?

**In a murder scene**, there may be blood.

**In a car accident**, there may be skin and bone.

**In war**, there may be ash from explosives.

It's grusome to discuss but these are real issues observant Jews have to deal with in today's world.

Is the rule simply to collect as much as humanly possible or is there a definition we are asked to follow when determining if we've done all we can?

Comment: I know that blood is required to be interred with the guf, although I've never learned the halachah inside

Comment: Are you asking about minimum or maximum? They try and get as much as they can, including soaking/wiping up blood with rags, and then burying the rags. In Israel, there's an organization called ZAKA that specializes in this sort of thing.

Comment: @DoubleAA The minimum. I was curious if there was a point where Halacha dictates you have done all that is reasonably possible or not. With zero restrictions I would expect the most strenuous Jew might actually dig up dirt or pavement soaked in blood to bury it. I readthey actually suggested burying the deceased inside of the vehicles destroyed on October 7th because they couldn't recover enough remains from inside the cars. They believed burying the whole car was the most appropriate thing to do.